# Shuffling an array with a condition

Tags: arrays, ruby, shuffle

Here's an array:

```
scramble = [
  "R", "U", "R' ", "U' ", "L", "L' ", "L2", "B", "B' ", 
  "B2", "F", "F' ", "F2", "R2", "U2", "D", "D' ", "D2"
]
```

I want to shuffle it with a condition such that `"R"`, `"R' "`, and `"R2"` are not together while shuffled, and similar for other letters.

`scramble.shuffle` does shuffle it, but how can I set such conditions?

Comment: You can't "set such conditions", you need to write an algorithm to do this. I would partition the array into N separate arrays containing the like elements, shuffle the individual arrays, and then recombine them by taking one element from a different array until all the arrays are empty. You need to make sure you don't leave yourself with too many elements in the final array.

Comment: `until (your_custom_condition) do array.shuffle! end`

Comment: @llya I'm not sure if you're joking, but that the worst possible way of doing this.

Comment: I am quite a beginner.. When finally made my dream "CUBE TIMER", this problem showed up outta nowhere :( 
If `R'` is beside `R` then there's no point in having these two at all. And if `R2` is beside `R'` then it's the same as `R` and vice versa. 
Implementing custom logic...

Comment: @meagar, llya's suggestion has one important thing going for it: it produces a random sequence (subject the limitations of  `shuffle` producing a truly random ordering). By contrast, with your suggested approach, suppose one of the groups of "like elements" contained a single element `e` and at least one of the other groups contained more than one element. The element `e` would never be selected last, so the approach would not generate a random sequencing....

Comment: ...to produce a random sequence, @llya's approach is the only one that comes to mind.

Comment: Ah, I should have recognized this as cube notation. So, instead of generating a list of moves and then trying to shuffle it until there are no redundant moves, why not just search for any adjacent redundancies and remove them, and append two new random moves to the end of the array to maintain its length? Note that it's possible to have longer sequences of redundant moves. `['R', 'R', 'R', 'R']` for example. You will have a very hard time finding and fixing all of them without actually modeling the cube and turning its faces, and looking for repeated states.

Comment: Alternatively, you could generate the sequence in a slightly smarter way and simply make sure that each step turns a different face than the previous step.

Comment: This is in principle a very difficult problem. Suppose, for example, there were `n` red objects and `n` blue objects, and no two same-coloured objects were to be adjacent in the resulting sequence. The only valid sequence would have the red and blue objects alternate, of which there are two, one beginning with a red object, the other a blue. If one were to adopt @llya's suggested approach the probability of drawing one of these two sequences would be `2**(-2n+1)`. If `n` were large, this would not be feasible, but neither would be any other algorithm that produces a random sequence.

Comment: Savage, I'm curious why you want to do this.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I have built a simple "Cube Timer". For an Example of so you could visit [link](http://cstimer.net). I have chosen the ARRAY way for the Scramble Notations. I don't know if there are any. 
As I said, If R' is beside R then there's no point in having these two at all. And if R2 is beside R' then it's the same as R and vice versa

Comment: @SavageHolycow You should simply generate a correct array in the first place, rather than generating a random array and trying to determine if it contains redundant turns. It's trivially easy to generate an array that doesn't turn the same side twice in a row.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've attempted to solve this problem in a general context. I've updated my answer with results on your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Juksefantomet** sent me this solution in discord, since he can't post here due to an account lock.

The below codeblock contains an alternative approach on how to tackle the problem at hand. This contains a fragmented solution to understand the steps on how you would normally approach a complex problem like the one presented above.

going through the various steps you can see how each condition has to be known in advance and specified to the point where your final array is not "illegal".

```
    @illegal_order = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

    puts @illegal_order.count

    puts "#{@illegal_order}"

    @foo = []

    # traverse the original array and append a random value from that into foo array
    # this can of course and should be done in a loop where you check for duplicates
    # this is done below in this example, fragmented to see the individual action
    (0..@illegal_order.count).each do |add_value|
        @temp = @illegal_order[rand(@illegal_order.count)]
        unless @foo.count == @illegal_order.count
            @foo.push(@temp)
        end
    end

    # making sure it contains everything in the original array
    @foo.each do |bar|
        unless @illegal_order.include?(bar)
            @approve = false
            puts "Errored generation!"
        end
    end

    # defining patterns, this can of course be extracted by the original array and be done alot cleaner
    # but printing it out to better break it down
    @pattern1 = [@illegal_order[0],@illegal_order[1],@illegal_order[2]]
    @pattern2 = [@illegal_order[3],@illegal_order[4],@illegal_order[5]]
    @pattern3 = [@illegal_order[6],@illegal_order[7],@illegal_order[8]]

    # Let us step through the new array and use case to check for various conditions that would flag the new array as invalid
    @foo.each do |step|
        # setting a temp pattern based on current state
        @temp_pattern = [@foo[step.to_i-1],@illegal_order[step.to_i],@illegal_order[step.to_i+1]]
        case step
        when @temp_pattern == @pattern1
            @illegalpatterns = true
        when @temp_pattern == @pattern2
            @illegalpatterns = true
        when @temp_pattern == @pattern3
            @illegalpatterns = true
        end
        # checking the foo array if it contains duplicates, if yes, set conditional to true
        @illegal_order.each do |count|
            if @foo.count(count) > 1
                @duplicates = true
            end
        end
    end

    # printing out feedback based on duplicates or not, this is where you rescramble the array if duplicate found
    (@duplicates == true) ? (puts "dupes found") : (puts "looks clear. no duplicates")
    # printing out feedback based on illegal patterns or not, this is where you rescramble the array if duplicate found
    (@illegalpatterns == true) ? (puts "illegal patterns found") : (puts "looks clear, no illegal patterns")

    puts "#{@foo}"
```

Comment: This seems massively overwrought. Why not just do this: https://gist.github.com/meagar/d484eb4a1868b83513dac2c61bc5710d

Comment: Or, in two lines: https://gist.github.com/meagar/5d45cffebefa563a8b3ca01e3abd9a4e

Comment: @meagar: Your solution is great, but the OP asked for a way to shuffle a given array so that some set of elements are not consecutive. In your solution there are chances that some elements may be repeated more than once, or some elements may not be present in final output. This anomaly doesn't make much impact if we are only concerned about shuffling a rubiks cube.

Comment: @AtulVaibhav it’s is desirable that elements repeat, the elements are not unique.

Comment: @AtulVaibhav Why? My comments are not answers, the question does not have to match them and my comments don’t have to match the question.

Comment: @meagar This two line one's so efficient and well thought! Great job!

Comment: @meagar I I'm taking this IDEA! 8-)

Answer (score 0):

Lets derive a generic solution.

Given a 2D array of groups of elements, return an array of shuffled elements such that no two consecutive elements belong to same group.

For example:

```
all_groups = [
  ["R", "R'", "R2" ],
  ["L", "L'", "L2" ],
  ["U", "U'", "U2" ],
  ["D", "D'", "D2" ],
  ["F", "F'", "F2" ],
  ["B", "B'", "B2" ]
]
```

Expected output:

```
["F'", "U'", "R'", "L2", "R2", "D2", "F2", "R", "L", "B", "F", "L'", "D'", "B'", "U2", "B2", "U", "D"]
```

---

*TL;DR* Code:

```
all_groups = [
  ["R", "R'", "R2" ],
  ["L", "L'", "L2" ],
  ["U", "U'", "U2" ],
  ["D", "D'", "D2" ],
  ["F", "F'", "F2" ],
  ["B", "B'", "B2" ]
]

ans = []

total = all_groups.map(&:length).reduce(:+)

# Initial shuffling
all_groups = all_groups.each { |i| i.shuffle! }.shuffle

until all_groups.empty?
  # Select and pop last group
  last_group = all_groups.pop

  # Insert last element to our ans, and remove from group
  ans.push(last_group.pop)
  total -= 1

  # Shuffle remaining groups
  all_groups.shuffle!

  # Check if any group has reached critical state
  length_of_longest_group = all_groups.reduce(0) { |len, i| [len, i.length].max }
  if length_of_longest_group * 2 == total + 1
    # Move that group to last
    # This ensures that next element picked is from this group
    longest_group = all_groups.detect { |i| i.length == length_of_longest_group }
    all_groups.delete(longest_group)
    all_groups.push(longest_group)
  end

  # Insert the last group at first place. This ensures that next element
  # is not from this group.
  all_groups.unshift(last_group) unless last_group.empty?
end

puts ans.inspect
```

Examples:

```
all_groups = [
  ["R", "R'", "R2" ],
  ["L", "L'", "L2" ],
  ["U", "U'", "U2" ],
  ["D", "D'", "D2" ],
  ["F", "F'", "F2" ],
  ["B", "B'", "B2" ]
]

# Output 1:
ans = ["B'", "U'", "L'", "U2", "R", "B2", "F2", "R2", "D2", "L2", "D", "R'", "U", "F'", "D'", "L", "F", "B"]
# Output 2:
ans = ["U'", "R", "D", "R'", "U", "D2", "B2", "D'", "L", "B", "L2", "B'", "U2", "F'", "L'", "F", "R2", "F2"]
# Output 3:
ans = ["B", "D", "R'", "D'", "B'", "R", "F2", "L", "D2", "B2", "F'", "R2", "U'", "F", "L'", "U2", "L2", "U"]
# Output 4:
ans = ["U'", "F'", "R2", "B2", "D", "L2", "B'", "U", "R", "B", "R'", "L'", "D'", "U2", "F", "D2", "F2", "L"]
# Output 5:
ans = ["U2", "F2", "L'", "F'", "R'", "F", "D'", "B2", "D2", "L", "B", "D", "L2", "B'", "R", "U", "R2", "U'"]



all_groups = [
  ['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'A', 'AA', 'AAA'],
  ['b', 'bb', 'bbb', 'B', 'BB', 'BBB'],
  ['c', 'cc', 'ccc', 'C', 'CC', 'CCC']
]
ans = ["c", "AAA", "B", "ccc", "bbb", "C", "AA", "CC", "aa", "BB", "CCC", "bb", "cc", "A", "BBB", "a", "b", "aaa"]


all_groups = [
  ['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5', 'r6', 'r7', 'r8'],
  ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8']
]

# Output1:
ans = ["r2", "b7", "r1", "b5", "r7", "b6", "r3", "b8", "r4", "b3", "r5", "b1", "r6", "b4", "r8", "b2"]
# Output2:
ans = ["b6", "r8", "b2", "r1", "b4", "r2", "b8", "r7", "b3", "r4", "b5", "r5", "b7", "r3", "b1", "r6"]
```

---

*Explanation:*

To begin with, lets shuffle the input data. First we shuffle each group, then we shuffle the outer array.

```
all_groups = all_groups.each { |i| i.shuffle! }.shuffle
```

Now our array looks like this:

```
[["B", "B2", "B'"],
 ["F'", "F", "F2"],
 ["L", "L2", "L'"],
 ["R2", "R'", "R"],
 ["D", "D'", "D2"],
 ["U'", "U", "U2"]]
```

Now, if we traverse this array in column-major order, we get a prety decent shuffling of elements wherein no two consecutive elements belong to same group.

```
["B", "F'", "L", "R2", "D", "U'", "B2", "F", "L2", "R'", "D'", "U", "B'", "F2", "L'", "R", "D2", "U2"]
```

But only flaw in this is that all elements of a particular group are equidistant. Lets improve.

So we have a set of groups. Lets select any one of group and then select the last element from that group and add this element to our answer array. Now shuffle the 2D array and repeat until all elements are selected.

Also, we don't want any two consecutive elements to belong to same group, so we need to ensure that the next selection of element is from some other group. So how about this strategy:

*Always pick the last group from our 2d array, and then once we shuffle we will ensure that this group is not the last group in 2d array.*

In terms of psuedocode:

```
1. Select last group from 2d array.
2. Remove an element from this group.
3. Shuffle the order of other groups in 2d array
4. Insert the selected group at begining.
```

For example, lets start with this 2d array:

```
[["D", "D'", "D2"],
 ["U", "U'", "U2"],
 ["B2", "B", "B'"],
 ["F2", "F", "F'"],
 ["L'", "L", "L2"],
 ["R'", "R2", "R"]]
```

last group: `["R'", "R2", "R"]`
Element removed: ("R")

Shuffle order of remaining groups of 2d array:

```
[["L'", "L", "L2"],
 ["B2", "B", "B'"],
 ["D", "D'", "D2"],
 ["U", "U'", "U2"],
 ["F2", "F", "F'"]]
```

2D array after inserting the popped group(the group from which we extracted an element)

```
[["R'", "R2"],
 ["L'", "L", "L2"],
 ["B2", "B", "B'"],
 ["D", "D'", "D2"],
 ["U", "U'", "U2"],
 ["F2", "F", "F'"]]
```

Now, since our logic selects the last group and then inserts it in the begining, we are insured that two elements of same group will never be picked in two consecutive turns.

A catch: There can be a possibility that there is a group which never reaches the last position, hence this group will never shrink, and its element will be forced to be picked consecutively once the number of elements is too less.
For example observe the output of 4 iterations of above algorithm on below input:

```
[['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'A', 'AA', 'AAA'],
 ['b', 'bb', 'bbb', 'B', 'BB', 'BBB'],
 ['c', 'cc', 'ccc', 'C', 'CC', 'CCC']]

  # Output 1: in this 'a' & 'aaa' are together
 ["CC", "bb", "C", "BB", "aa", "bbb", "AA", "CCC", "b", "c", "B", "cc", "A", "BBB", "AAA", "ccc", "a", "aaa"]

  # Output 2: in this 'b' & 'BB' are together
 ["cc", "A", "B", "c", "AAA", "C", "a", "ccc", "bbb", "CCC", "aaa", "bb", "CC", "aa", "BBB", "AA", "b", "BB"]

  # Output 3: this is perfect
 ["CCC", "BB", "a", "c", "BBB", "aa", "bbb", "A", "bb", "ccc", "B", "CC", "AAA", "b", "AA", "cc", "aaa", "C"]

  # Output 4: in this 'c' & 'cc' are together
 ["CC", "bb", "AA", "b", "aa", "BBB", "aaa", "bbb", "CCC", "B", "A", "BB", "C", "a", "ccc", "AAA", "c", "cc"]
```

So, there are chances that when ratio of `number of elements in a group` to `total no of elements` increases, two elements of same group can be clubbed together. Hmm, lets improve further:

Since the group with maximum number of elements has most probability of having two elements combined consecutively, lets study such groups. i.e. group with maximum number of elements.

Lets say, there is a group with X number of elements  in it. So what is the minimum number of other type of elements required that none of the X elements are consecutive? Simple right: insert a different element between each pair of element of this group.

```
x * x * x * x * x * x
```

So we realise, that if group has `X` elements it requires atleast `(X-1)` other type of elements so that no two elements of this group get consecutive.
Mathematically the condition can be represented as:

```
    number_of_elements_in_longest_group     == number_of_other_type_of_elements + 1
=>  number_of_elements_in_longest_group     == (total_number_of_elements - number_of_elements_in_longest_group) + 1
=>  number_of_elements_in_longest_group * 2 == total_number_of_elements + 1
```

Going back to our algorithm, lets add a condition, that at any point of time, if number of remaining items is 1 less than the number of elements in largest group then we have to ensure that next element picked is from this largest group

Comment: My understanding is that the OP wishes to randomly select a sequence among all "valid" sequences. I do not believe your solution satisfies the "random" requirement. Suppose, for example, that your `all_groups` array were `[a,b,c,d]` where `a=["a1", "a2",...,"a100"]`, `b=["b1","b2"..."b100"]`, `c=["c1","c2"..."c100"]` and `d = ["d1"]`.  The location of `d1` in each randomly drawn "valid" sequence should be more-or-less randomly distributed among the 301 possible positions. You procedure, however, would tend to put `d1` near the beginning of each sequence.

Comment: @CarySwoveland correct, problem in my solution is that I'm treating all groups with same probability. I'll try to add the length of each group as weights when determining from which group next element should belong.